# typedef struct on Arduino : variable does not name a type

Tags: c++, c, struct, arduino, typedef

I want to make a `typedef struct` ( or similar, if i can't ) on arduino mega for 20 sensors, but i have a error and i don't understand why. Is it from arduino compilation or from my code ? Do you think that i must to put my code on a header file ?

```
 typedef struct {
          char nom[8]; 
          int pin; 
          int onOff; 
          int pente;
          int offset;
          int maximun;
          int minimum;
          int constante1;
          int constante2;
          int hyst1;
          int hyst2;
          float moyenne; 
          float valeurs[]; 
          int frequence; 
        } structSondes;

    structSondes sondes[20];
    structSondes test;
    sondes[0].pin=1;
    test.pin=1;
```

I have this error on the compilation :

> error: ‘sondes’ does not name a type
>
> error: ‘test’ does not name a type

Comment: the error, its showing `sonde` or `sondes`? also, the `float valeurs[];` must come in end (as per `C99`).

Comment: @SouravGhosh sorry, it's "sondes"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not provided your complete code, so it possible only to guess.

I suspect that the problem is that the statements:

```
 sondes[0].pin=1;
 test.pin=1;
```

are written in the body of the ino file, not inside a function.

Comment: Why is this the case? That struct entities must be assigned inside functions only?